# Wax stripping on Shabbat

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, hair

Is there a halachic issue of wax strips for hair on Shabbat? These are sticky wax strips typically placed on arms and legs which when detached pull off some of the hair

I know there is a prohibition of sewing, but that doesn’t apply to human skin. This also isn’t medical treatment. Beyond this are there any halachic concerns?

Comment: Unrelated to Shabbat, but if I remember correctly there's an issue of Lo Yilbash in shaving/ stripping hair (besides for head/facial hair) for men

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Stripping hair is forbidden on Shabbat because of the *melacha* of *gozez*. Doing so with a tool explicitly meant to strip hair is a Biblical prohibition.**

From [chabad.org](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/4844108/jewish/Gozez-Shearing.htm)

> Shearing, the av melachah of **gozez**, **is forbidden on Shabbat**, and
> involves **cutting or uprooting hair**, nails, or anything else that grows
> from a person, animal, or bird.
>
> The Biblical prohibition of gozez is only transgressed if one uses an
> instrument meant for that purpose, like a pair of scissors or a nail
> clipper. [...]

See also [here](https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/01-14-01/).